# Installing mysql problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql.sock

Running OS X Leopard an MacBook Pro from Jan. 2008.

I used to run mysql server from a package but then rails started putting a warning that I should install mysql from gem: gem install mysql

It did not work, I got the following error message:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb install mysql
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
... snip ...
Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7 for inspection.

### Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/gem_make.out

Then I tried a different way, upon a friend's advice and tried to follow the excellent instructions at http://hivelogic.com/articles/2007/11/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x
but now ran into a new problem when trying to run 'mysql -u root'

The message I get is:

### ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I have googled my heart out trying to fix either problem and feel stuck. Thanks for reading and helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the first problem - I would imagine that Ruby gem is installing the ruby MySQL interface/drivers, not the MySQL server itself. It may be not present, or in a place the standard scripts can't find.

The second message indicates that the MySQL server is not running. Try starting it again, or examine any logs/messages for some indication as to why it might not be starting